# Is there a way to update the environment variables in a batch file without restarting it?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

**BACKROUND:**
I am using a program that uses an older jkd, jdk-9.0.4, to be specific. It needs the JAVA_HOME value to be set to jdk-9.0.4. I don't want to use jdk-9.0.4 otherwise, so I wrote a batch file to switch to jdk-9.0.4, run the program, and switch back to jdk-14 at the end.

**CODE EXCERPT:**

```
SETX /m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4"
GRADLEW runClient
SETX /m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14"
```

**PROBLEM:**
I believe cmd only reads environment variables at the launch of the file, so even though I update the JAVA_HOME value with `SETX` it does not acknowledge it. I am looking for some sort of command that could refresh cmd's environment variable values. I am looking for a solution that is not running two separate batch files (One to update JAVA_HOME to jdk-9.0.4 and one to run the program and reset JAVA_HOME).

**RESEARCH:**
When I look this up online all I can find us the whole *cmd only reads environment variables at the launch of the file* bit and the only solution it offers is to restart cmd to get the updated values. Ideally though I do not want to do that.

Comment: [`setx`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) sets variables for the *next* execution of `cmd.exe` (actually it writes to the registry, which is read by `cmd` upon start-up), [`set`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) for the current one; so perhaps in your situation it could help to simply add `set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4"` as the first or second line...

Comment: @aschip Haha that works thanks

Comment: I think the question should rather be why your program won’t run with a newer jdk? There are a bunch of problems to run into when going from 8 to 9, but from there on It should just work in most cases.

Comment: Its modding another application which uses an older jdk, so I think that is why, but I'm not exactly sure.